# How do I select those records where the group by clause returns 2 or more?

Tags: sql

I'd like to return a list of items of only those that have two or more in the group:

```
select count(item_id) from items group by type_id;
```

Specifically, I'd like to know the values of item_id when the count(item_id) == 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for something that's not particularly possible without a subquery.

Basically, you want to list all values in a column while aggregating on that same column. You can't do this. Aggregating on a column makes it impossible to list of all the individual values from that column.

What you can do is find all `type_id` values which have an `item_id` count equal to 2, then select all `item_id`s from records matching those `type_id` values:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM items
WHERE type_id IN (
  SELECT type_id
  FROM items
  GROUP BY type_id
  HAVING COUNT(item_id) = 2
)
```

This is best expressed using a join rather than a `WHERE IN` clause, but the idea is the same no matter how you approach it. You may also want to select distinct `item_id`s in which case you'll need the `DISTINCT` keyword before `item_id` in the outer query.

Comment: Possible enhancements include using `>= 2` if you really mean "two or more", and/or moving the inner query into the `FROM` clause as a joined table (enhancing performance in some engines).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query:

```
select count(item_id) from items group by type_id having count(item_id)=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL dialect includes `GROUP_CONCAT()`, that could be used to generate a list of items without the inner query.  However, the results differ; the inner query returns one item id per row, where `GROUP_CONCAT()` returns multiple ids as a string.

```
SELECT type_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item_id), COUNT(item_id) as number
FROM items
GROUP BY type_id
HAVING number = 2
```